# How do you initialize a UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add a gesture recognizer to my button so that I can run code if the user swiped past the buttons frame. I also want this code to be different if the swipe was up, right, left, or down the button.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    UIGestureRecognizer *swipe=[[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:button action:@selector(detectSwipe)];
    [button addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
}
```

so, did I do the `initWithTarget:action:` thing correct? And now that I do this how do i Implement the `detectSwipe` method?

here is my idea on how to implement `detectSwipe`

```
          -(IBAction)detectSwipe:(UIButton *)sender
        {
      /* I dont know how to put this in code but i would need something like, 
if (the swipe direction is forward and the swipe is > sender.frame ){ 
[self ForwardSwipeMethod];
    } else if //same thing for right
    else if //same thing for left
    else if //same thing for down

        }
```

Comment: detectSwipe: doesn't get the button as sender. It's the gesture recognizer that is passed in as the argument - or how else would you know which recognizer detected and what gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to be using a [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). UIGestureRecognizer usually shouldnt be used unless you are subclassing it. Your code should look similar to the following.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectSwipe)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[button addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't correct. The target of the gesture recognizer is not the button, it's the object on which it calls the action method when detecting a gesture (otherwise how would it know on which object call that method? In OO, a method call/message send needs an explicit method name **and** an instance or class).

So you would most likely want

```
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
```

You also don't create an instance of UIGestureRecognizer directly but one if its concrete subclasses, UISwipeGestureRecognizer in this case.

After alloc-initting the recognizer, you attach it to the view you want to be recognized:

```
[button addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Then in the didSwipe: method, you can use the gesture recognizer's properties to decide what the size/distance/other property of the swipe was.

[You better read some docs next time.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

You got all right except for the target of gesture recogniser. The target is an object that receives given selector message so your `initWithTarget:` call should accept `self` as an argument unless you're implementing `detectSwipe` method in a subclass of your button.

Answer (score 1):

H2CO3's answer is complete. Just don't forget that you're missing a colon ":" at the end of your selector! It should be like this: `@selector(detectSwipe:)`

The colon ":" is because your method has an argument: `(UIButton *)sender`